# How can I access an array of structs within a struct?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, stack

I have the following two structures:

```
typedef struct stack * StackPtr;
typedef struct book * BookPtr;

struct book {
    char *title;
    int pages;
};

struct stack {
    int num_books;
    Book array[50] // changed from Book *array[50]
};
```

Here is how I'm initialising each structure:

```
StackPtr create_stack(void) {
    StackPtr s = malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    s->num_books = 0;
    return s;
}

BookPtr create_book(char *title, int pages) {
    BookPtr b = malloc(sizeof(struct book));
    b->title = strdup(title);
    b->pages = pages;
    return b;
}
```

I am trying to access the title and the pages of the book using the array inside the stack struct. This is how I am doing it:

For example, if I want to access and modify the title and pages of the last book in the struct, I am dong this:

```
(s->array[s->num_books-1])->title = strdup(new_title);
(s->array[s->num_books-1])->pages = new_pages;
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
error: member reference base type 'Book' (aka 'struct book *') is not a structure or union
        (s->array[s->num_books-1])->title = strdup(new_title);
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^ ~~~~~
```

Edit: after I removed the pointer from `Book *array[50];` I am now getting this error:

```
error: incomplete definition of type 'struct book'
        (s->array[s->num_books-1])->title = strdup(new_title);
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

I thought this was a problem with main not being able to see the book structure so I stopped using header files and put everything in one file but that didn't help.

I also think that I am not initialising the stack properly.

When I try to initialize the array in the create_stack function like this:

```
s->array = malloc(sizeof(BookPtr) * 50); //inside create_array function
```

This is the error I get:

```
array type 'BookPtr *[50]' is not assignable
```

Comment: `Book *array[50];` creates an *array of pointers to book 50* not *50 struct book*.

Comment: `typedef struct stack * Stack;` is a misleading `typedef`. Use `typedef struct stack Stack;` or `typedef struct stack * StackPtr;`

Comment: @David Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Sure, If you want to create an array of 50 struct book, use `Book array[50];`, then you will access something like `s->book[i].title`. If you create an array of uninitialized pointers to struct book (e.g. `Book *array[50];`), you must allocate memory for each pointer before you can assign values to the members, etc. (you can do it this way, you just have to manage the memory allocation for each Book)

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to use dynamic memory allocation for these members?  i.e. Do you know at run-time how many array members you will need?

Comment: @RSahu I made changes according to your suggestion.

Comment: @user6005857, now, you have to update rest of your post to keep with it.

Comment: **Never** `typedef` a pointer!

Comment: Your first edit broke your code because you changed `Book` to `BookPtr` in one place but not the other.

Comment: Problems such as you've encountered are one of the prime reasons to follow @Olaf's advice and never hide pointer nature behind a `typedef`.  Not even one whose name ends in "p" or "Ptr".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear whether you ever got this solved, so perhaps a short example will help. Regardless whether you create storage for X number of books in `array` at the beginning or create `array` as an an array of X pointers to books, you will need some way of insuring you do not add more books than you can store. The obvious way to handle this is to add one additional variable to your `stack` struct that tracks the storage (or number of pointers available) in `array` and then `realloc` `array` as required. To track the space in `array` available, you could simply add another counter, say `max_books`, e.g.

```
enum { NBOOKS = 10 };

typedef struct {
    char *title;
    int pages;
} book;

typedef struct {
    int num_books,
        max_books;
    book *array;
} stack;
```

Since there is no benefit in declaring an `array` as an *array of pointers* when you are simply going to create storage for each book, you may as well just declare array as `book *array;` and allocate storage for some reasonably anticipated number of books to begin with. Your `create_stack` isn't far off, but I would do `add_book` a little differently, in order to create the stack if it is currently `NULL` and `realloc` as required. Something like the following:

```
/** since add_book may create the stack, you must pass the address
 *  of the stack to add_book so that any changes to s are available
 *  back in the calling funciton.
 */
book *add_book (stack **s, char *title, int pages)
{
    if (!title) return NULL;        /* validate title */
    if (!*s) *s = create_stack ();  /* if stack NULL, create */

    /* check num_books against max_books and realloc as required */
    if ((*s)->num_books == (*s)->max_books) {
        void *tmp = realloc ((*s)->array, ((*s)->max_books + NBOOKS) * 
                            sizeof *((*s)->array));
        if (!tmp) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: memory exhausted - realloc array.\n");
            return NULL;
        }
        (*s)->array = tmp;
        (*s)->max_books += NBOOKS;
    }

    /* allocate/copy title, assign pages, increment num_books */
    (*s)->array[(*s)->num_books].title = strdup (title);
    (*s)->array[(*s)->num_books].pages = pages;
    ((*s)->num_books)++;

    /* change return as desired, I just return the address of the book
     * to indicate success and provide a way to validate the add.
     */
    return &((*s)->array[(*s)->num_books - 1]);
}
```

(*note*: the comment on why the stack is passed to the function as `stack **`)

Those are basically the changes you would need to create your *stack of books* that would allow you to add as many books as you would like (until you exhaust the memory of your computer). Putting the example together, you can do something like the following (*note:* the constant `NBOOKS` must be greater than zero, you can add checks to insure)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { NBOOKS = 10 };

typedef struct {
    char *title;
    int pages;
} book;

typedef struct {
    int num_books,
        max_books;
    book *array;
} stack;

stack *create_stack ();
book *add_book (stack **s, char *title, int pages);
void prn_stack (stack *s);
void free_stack (stack *s);

int main (void) {

    stack *s1 = NULL;   /* always initialize your pointers */

    add_book (&s1, "Huck Finn", 631);
    add_book (&s1, "Tom Sawyer", 582);
    add_book (&s1, "The Quick Brown Fox", 1);

    prn_stack (s1);
    free_stack (s1);

    return 0;
}

/** allocate stack and allocate storage for NBOOKS books */
stack *create_stack ()
{
    stack *s = calloc (1, sizeof *s);
    if (!s) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted - stack.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    s->array = calloc (NBOOKS, sizeof *(s->array));
    if (!s->array) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted - array.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    s->num_books = 0;
    s->max_books = NBOOKS;

    return s;
}

/** since add_book may create the stack, you must pass the address
 *  of the stack to add_book so that any changes to s are available
 *  back in the calling funciton.
 */
book *add_book (stack **s, char *title, int pages)
{
    if (!title) return NULL;        /* validate title */
    if (!*s) *s = create_stack ();  /* if stack NULL, create */

    /* check num_books against max_books and realloc as required */
    if ((*s)->num_books == (*s)->max_books) {
        void *tmp = realloc ((*s)->array, ((*s)->max_books + NBOOKS) * 
                            sizeof *((*s)->array));
        if (!tmp) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: memory exhausted - realloc array.\n");
            return NULL;
        }
        (*s)->array = tmp;
        (*s)->max_books += NBOOKS;
    }

    /* allocate/copy title, assign pages, increment num_books */
    (*s)->array[(*s)->num_books].title = strdup (title);
    (*s)->array[(*s)->num_books].pages = pages;
    ((*s)->num_books)++;

    /* change return as desired, I just return the address of the book
     * to indicate success and provide a way to validate the add.
     */
    return &((*s)->array[(*s)->num_books - 1]);
}

void prn_stack (stack *s)
{
    if (!s) return;

    printf ("\nThere are %d books in the stack:\n\n", s->num_books);
    for (int i = 0; i < s->num_books; i++)
        printf ("  %2d.  %-20s  (%3d pages)\n", i, s->array[i].title, s->array[i].pages);
    putchar ('\n');
}

void free_stack (stack *s)
{
    if (!s) return;

    for (int i = 0; i < s->num_books; i++)
        free (s->array[i].title);
    free (s->array);
    free (s);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/bookstack

There are 3 books in the stack:

   0.  Huck Finn             (631 pages)
   1.  Tom Sawyer            (582 pages)
   2.  The Quick Brown Fox   (  1 pages)
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

Setting `NBOOKS` TO `2` to force reallocation and checking with `valgrind`, you will find:

```
$ valgrind ./bin/bookstack
==15521== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==15521== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==15521== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==15521== Command: ./bin/bookstack
==15521==

There are 3 books in the stack:

   0.  Huck Finn             (631 pages)
   1.  Tom Sawyer            (582 pages)
   2.  The Quick Brown Fox   (  1 pages)

==15521==
==15521== HEAP SUMMARY:
==15521==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15521==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 6 frees, 153 bytes allocated
==15521==
==15521== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==15521==
==15521== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==15521== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
```

Which is how it should be. Look things over and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

You have defined `Book` as a *pointer* to `struct book` and then you are defining an array of pointers of type `Book`, which means it's an array of *pointers to pointers* to `struct book`.

Either define `Book` as `struct book` or remove the pointer from after `Book` in the array definition. Usually the former since you didn't name it clearly as `BookPtr` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so I will expound on David C. Rankin's comment.  Your definition of array won't work.

You probably should use one of the following...

This gives you an array of Book that will hold at most 50 books:

```
Book array[50];
```

This gives you a pointer to an array of Book that has no size limit, but requires more overhead.

```
Book *array;
```

If you use the latter, you will have to create the array, keep track of its current length, and make it bigger when you've filled it up (see https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc).

Comment: I did that but I get this error `incomplete definition of type 'struct book'` at this line: `(s->array[s->num_books - 1])->title = strdup(title);`

Comment: I don't understand.  Could you edit the original post to add your new code without removing the original code?